# Set HTML <img> element to Javascript image variable

Tags: javascript, html, image, set, sequence

I have an array of image variables that get preloaded using javascript to make an image sequence animation. The issue I have is setting the img element from HTML to use one of these images. It seems all the properies are strings?

Here's how I set the array of images in javascript:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 30; i ++){
    anim[i] = new Image();
    if(i < 10){
        anim[i].src = "images/anim/frame0" + i + ".png";
    }
    if(i >= 10){
        anim[i].src = "images/anim/frame" + i + ".png";
    }
}
```

and I simply have an 
    ^img tag = "animation"^ 
in html that I want to change.

Comment: provide us some code samples please

Comment: How? Can you post your code in the question.

Comment: I would probably use some CSS keyframes for creating an animation if the images are not dynamically created or fetched from database. See: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp 
You won't need javascript for that and it would be much faster and smoother

Comment: I'll check it out

Comment: My only concern with that is it's surely going to have to fetch the image every time I change the animation frame, with no preloading?

Comment: You can change `background-image` of the element every 0.1s for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks valid.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    anim[i] = new Image();

    if(i < 10){
        anim[i].src = `images/anim/frame0${i}.png`;
    }

    if(i >= 10){
        anim[i].src = `images/anim/frame${i}.png`;
    }
}
```

Now you can do:
`document.body.appendChild(anim[0]);`

I tested this and it works for me.

If you want to change `src` on the fly then you'd have to select the appended element and update its src like this: `document.querySelectorAll('img')[0].src = newSourceVariable;`.

Comment: oh awesome, and i'll need to delete the old image object right?

Comment: is there any way to just replace the old image? It has some properties that I need it to keep, as well as a parallax scroll function that uses the original object.

Comment: Yes, either delete the old image (not recommended because you'll have flickering animation) or update the `src` by selecting the already appended image. With jQuery you'd do `$('img').eq(0).attr('src', newSource);` to replace the `src` of already existing image.

Comment: With pure JS you'd do: `document.querySelectorAll('img')[0].src = newSourceVariable;` - it will select the appended image and replace the `src` of already existing image. You can do this in a loop as well.

Comment: So after a few more days of trying I've got it working using AppendChild. Thanks bud :)